# Git clone with preexisting public key

Tags: git, ssh

I have a requirement in which a script must be able to clone some git repositories using a preexisting public key (simply copying it to /home/user/.ssh).

What I am asking is if this is possible without the private key. HTTPS is not an option.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need a private key to authenticate to SSH (GIT). Other possibility is to use password.

Comment: And the public and private key must be generated at the same time. Or I can just generate a private key and use the preexisting public one?

Comment: The private key is mathematically connected to the public key so if you want the authentication to succeed, they need to be "related". So no, you can no generate a private key for the general public key (but you can do it the other way round).